# platex.exe not created in w32tex

Tags: platex

I just downloaded texist2015 (latest update 2015 Sept. 26th, today!)
and make a standardinstallation of w32tex.
Everything went well except that the most important component

platex.exe

is not created in the w32tex/bin directory !

I retried several time by downloading install files from different mirrors without success. Please help !

Thank you very much.

EDIT:
Dear all, many thanks very much for your prompt replies.
Yes I meant texinst2015 very sorry for the misspelling,
and platex is for producing Japanese documents from w32tex
maintained by Akiro Kakuto.
http://w32tex.org/index-ja.html

Dear Akiro Kakuto, it is nice to find you here.
You are right: I forgot to download ptex-w32 !! 
Shame on me. I spent several hours to find out the problem yesterday, and it was that....Many thanks.

Comment: Can you give a bit more details? I have never heard of `texist2015`, have just googled it and found nothing relevant. I have also never heard of `platex.exe`, did you mean `pdflatex.exe` or `latex.exe`?

Comment: @moewe `platex` is LaTeX built using the e-pTeX engine: Japanese typesetting.

Comment: @Xavier I'm not sure why you've mentioned both TeX Live and w32tex. TeX Live and w32tex are 'related' (the Windows binaries in TL are those from w32tex, for example), but they are separately-installable TeX systems. Can you detail exactly what you did and any error messages you got.

Comment: Xavier is saying texinst2015.zip, which simply expands downloaded archives.
Maybe there are errors in downloading.
platex.exe is in ptex-w32.tar.xz.